# Program reports an error that apparently doesn't exist

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

When running the program after compiling it using the commands `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall -Wextra myprogram.f95` the following error appears

```
Fortran runtime error: Substring out of bounds: lower bound (0) of 'x' is less than one
```

It is also reported that the error lies on line 10 of the following subroutine.

```
 01 subroutine create_table_MP (x, m, t)
 02   implicit none
 03   character(len=*), intent(in) :: x
 04   integer, dimension(0:), intent(inout) :: t
 05   integer, intent(in) :: m
 06   integer :: i, j
 07   i=0; t(0)=-1; j=-1
 08   do while (i < m)
 09       if (j > -1) then
 10           do while ((j>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(x((j+1):(j+1)))))
 11               j = t(j)
 12           end do
 13       end if
 14       i=i+1; j=j+1; t(i)=j
 15   end do
 16 end subroutine create_table_MP
```

But the `if(j > -1)` command guarantees that none of the subscripts of the line 10 is zero, so I don't understand why this error occurred.
I put a `print *, j+1` before line 10 and, as expected, j+1 never assumes zero value.
I don't know where the error is. Could someone please help me?

The code of the entire program in which this subroutine was used is

```
module search
    implicit none

contains
    subroutine MP (x, y, m, n)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: x, y
        integer, intent(in) :: m, n
        integer, dimension(0:m-1) :: table
        integer :: i, j

        call create_table_MP(x, m, table)

        i=0; j=0

        do while (j<n)
            do while ((i>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(y((j+1):(j+1)))))
                i = table(i)
            end do

            i=i+1; j=j+1

            ! if (i >= m) then
            !     print *, j-i
            !     i = table(i)
            ! end if
        end do
    end subroutine MP

    subroutine KMP (x, y, m, n)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: x, y
        integer, intent(in) :: m, n
        integer, dimension(0:m-1) :: table
        integer :: i, j

        call create_table_KMP(x, m, table)

        i=0; j=0

        do while(j<n)
            do while((i>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(y((j+1):(j+1)))))
                i = table(i)
            end do

            i=i+1; j=j+1

            ! if (i >= m) then
            !     print *, j-i
            !     i = table(i)
            ! end if

        end do
    end subroutine KMP

    subroutine create_table_MP (x, m, t)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: x
        integer, dimension(0:), intent(inout) :: t
        integer, intent(in) :: m
        integer :: i, j

        i=0; t(0)=-1; j=-1

        do while (i < m)
            if (j > -1) then
                do while ((j>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(x((j+1):(j+1)))))
                    j = t(j)
                end do
            end if

            i=i+1; j=j+1; t(i)=j
        end do
    end subroutine create_table_MP

    subroutine create_table_KMP (x, m, t)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: x
        integer, dimension(0:), intent(inout) :: t
        integer, intent(in) :: m
        integer :: i, j

        i=0; t(0)=-1; j=-1

        do while (i < m)
            if (j > -1) then
                do while ((j>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(x((j+1):(j+1)))))
                    j = t(j)
                end do
            end if

            i=i+1; j=j+1

            if ((i<m).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))==ichar(x((j+1):(j+1))))) then
                t(i) = t(j)
            else
                t(i) = j
            end if

        end do
    end subroutine create_table_KMP
end module search

program test
    use search
    implicit none
    character(len=*), parameter :: string1 = 'gga', file1 = 'file.txt'

    call search_1(string1, file1)

contains
    subroutine search_1 (string,name_file)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: string, name_file
        character(len=200) :: message
        integer :: l_character
        logical :: exist1 = .false., iend = .true.

        inquire(FILE=name_file, EXIST=exist1)
        if(.not.(exist1)) then
            print *,'The file ',name_file,' doesnt exist.'
            print *,'Press ENTER to finish the program.'
            read (*,*)
            stop
        end if

        open(UNIT=10, FILE=name_file, STATUS='OLD')
        do
            read(UNIT=10, FMT='(A)', END=1000) message; iend=.false.
            1000 if(iend) then
                    exit
                end if

            call remove(message,l_character)

            iend = .true.
            if (l_character < 1) cycle

            call MP(string, message(1:l_character),len_trim(string), len_trim(message(1:l_character)))
            call KMP(string, message(1:l_character),len_trim(string),len_trim(message(1:l_character)))

        end do

        close(UNIT=10)
    end subroutine search_1

    subroutine remove (message, j)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(inout) :: message
        integer, intent(inout) :: j
        integer :: i

        i=1; j=1
        do
            if (i>len_trim(message)) exit
            ! ichar(a) = 97 and ichar(t) = 116
            if ((ichar(message(i:i))>=97).and.(ichar(message(i:i))<=116)) then
                message(j:j) = message(i:i)
                j = j + 1
            end if
            i = i + 1
        end do

        j = j - 1

    end subroutine remove
end program test
```

Comment: Is `t(j)` ever less than zero for that line 11?

Comment: Please do not use external hostings for important  information like code. Links rot with time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in the if statement at line 9 guarantees only that `j` is not negative only for the first iteration of the loop commencing at line 10.  At line 11, inside that loop, we can see that `j` takes a value given by `t(j)`.  Whether this is negative is not checked by that if statement.

That is, assume `j` is positive.  Then line 9 passes with a `.TRUE.` and the loop commencing at line 10 has its condition checked.  The left-hand side of the while condition expression is `.TRUE.` and let's assume the right-hand side is also.  So that the loop iterates.

At some point, perhaps `j(t)` becomes negative.  Then we get back to line 10 and a check of the while condition.  At that point, we see the out of bound error for x: recall that the if statement hasn't been hit and the expression with `.AND.` isn't short-circuited.  [That is, the left-hand side `j>-1` doesn't ensure that the right-hand side is evaluated with `j` non-negative.]

Answer (score 2):

Add some print statements and you will see how it goes with `t(0)=-1`, when you are in the inner loop. The next thing is to test `((j>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(x((j+1):(j+1)))))` with `j=0` which generates what you do not understand for now.

```
program myprogram
    integer, parameter :: M = 11
    character(M-1) :: x = "0123456789"
    integer, dimension(M) :: t

    call create_table_MP (x, m, t)
contains
    subroutine create_table_MP (x, m, t)
    implicit none
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: x
    integer, dimension(0:), intent(inout) :: t
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer :: i, j
    i=0; t(0)=-1; j=-1
    do while (i < m)
        if (j > -1) then
            write(*,*), "outer j = ", j
            do while ((j>-1).and.(ichar(x((i+1):(i+1)))/=ichar(x((j+1):(j+1)))))
                j = t(j)
                write(*,*), "  innerj = ", j
            end do
        end if
        i=i+1; j=j+1; t(i)=j
    end do
    end subroutine create_table_MP
end program myprogram
```